# pbs cluster - python multiple simulations

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, pbs, mpi4py

I have to run multiple simulations of the same model with varying parameters (or random number generator seed). Previously I worked on a server with many cores, where I used python multiprocessing library with apply_async. This was very handy as I could decide the maximum number of cores to occupy and simulations would just go into a queue.

Now I moved to a place with a hpc cluster working with pbs. It seems from trial and error and different answers that multiprocessing works only inside one node. Is there a way to make it work on many nodes, or any other library which reaches the same funtionality with the same easyness to use in few lines?

To let you understand my kind of code:

```
import functions_library as L
import multiprocessing as mp
if __name__ == "__main__":

    N = 100

    proc = 50
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = proc)



    seed = 342
    np.random.seed(seed)

    seeds = np.random.randint(low=1,high=100000,size=N)

    resul = []
    for SEED in seeds:

        SEED = int(SEED)

        resul.append(pool.apply_async(L.some_function, args = (some_args)))
        print(SEED)

    results = [p.get() for p in resul]

    database = pd.DataFrame(results)


    database.to_csv("prova.csv")
```

EDIT

As I understand, mpi4py might be helpful as naturally interacts with pbs. Is that correct? How can I adapt my code to mpi4py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the [`schwimmbad`](https://schwimmbad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package is quite handy to run code written for `multiprocessing` in an MPI cluster with minimal changes.

I hope it helps!

Comment: This sure looks promising, I will give it a try!

Comment: Thanks, it works really well! However I run into an issue you might already know something about: when running with few processes per node, it works well. When instead I run using 2 full nodes, I receive an error "PSM_SHAREDCONTEXTS_MAX=16". I am running the demo_example from schwimmbad but with my function instead of the demo one.

Comment: Also, decreasing the number of jobes per node just decreases the max in the error message to 8 and then 4. I'm running exactly the demo now to sort this out.